# What is the bodyguard handing over to the shadow warrior?

Tags: kagemusha

In the movie, Kagemusha (shadow warrior), when the shadow warrior is no longer needed he leaves the castle and his former bodyguard hands him over something.

Does anyone know what it is? It looks like a letter. But if it is a letter, it would be of any use to this shadow warrior.

[image]